# Does bragg diffraction affect intensity of transmitted light?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics

Is it possible to measure the plane spacing in a crystal by measuring the angle at which transmitted light intensity dips?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but: you can determine the spacing of *any* grating by observing the location of the diffraction peaks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by light you mean X-rays (with wavelengths comparable to the lattice spacing), then yes, it is possible to do transmission x-ray diffraction studies, and gain similar information about the structure. However this technique is very rarely used, and has a number of limitations compared to traditional x-ray diffraction. For and example and details see the following article: http://www.clays.org/journal/archive/volume%2047/47-5-637.pdf

However, if you are referring to transmitted intensity of visible light, the most you can glean from the data is the thickness of a thin film sample, you will get no information about lattice spacing.